# For a low pass filter, derivephase of the transfer function, Vout/Vin

Tags: capacitor, resistance, low-pass, transfer-function, phase

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSOEU2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have calculated the magnitude:

\$ ||H(j\omega)|| = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 + {(RC\omega)}^2}} \$

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please be as specific as possible. Tell us how much you understand.

Comment: Sounds like homework. Think of it in terms of complex numbers: The magnitude of a+ bj + sqrt(a^2 + b^2_)  the angle is then atan(b/a)

Answer (score 1):

[A quick Google search does provide the answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit#Gain_and_phase), but maybe you are after a somewhat easy and intuitive way to find the answer.

Well, the phase response is the argument (or phase) of the transfer function. Manipulate the transfer function just like a complex number.

Remember that \$1 = e^0\$, so the inverse of a complex number will negate the phase (that is, \$\arg{}(1/c)\ = - \arg{}(c)\$). That's because if you were to write \$c\$ in exponential form, the exponents subtract when using division.

The argument of a complex number \$a + bj\$ is \$\arctan\left(b/a\right)\$. So mapping \$a = 1\$ and \$b = RC\omega\$, one obtains your solution:

$$\arg(H(j\omega))=-\arctan\left({RC\omega}\right)$$

Just remember that transfer functions are basically functions that "generates" complex numbers that tells the amplitude and phase of the function for all \$j\omega\$. Thus, to obtain the magnitude and phase response of a transfer function you basically use the appropriate tools to obtain the absolute/argument of the complex function.